# mouse event in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mouseevent

> ### Hi Everybody I want to do somthing in react.

**`I want when I move the mouse on body I want to show somthing such a (logo).`**

**`and after that show something else such a (form).`**

**`I want if mouse donot move on body donot show logo and as well form.`**

**`I mean that logo and form connect to each other.`**

**what should I do.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the on MouseOver event to achieve this. Link to w3schools demo
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover